# Can't route into WAN with IPCop Router

Tags: linux, firewall, ip, routing, gateway

i try to setup a IPCOP Router but i can't access the WAN from LAN but the LAN from WAN works fine. Example:

```
WAN IP from IPCOP 192.168.1.130/26
WAN IP aliase from IPCOP 192.168.1.131 ... 190 /26
WAN IP from Gateway for IPCOP 192.168.1.129/26

LAN IP from IPCOP 10.1.1.1/24
```

When i log into IPCOP i can access the WAN, on a Client on LAN side i can ping the 10.1.1.1 and the 192.168.1.130 but i can't access the 192.168.1.129, but from IPCOP it works.

```
#route -n 
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.128    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth1
10.1.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.129    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
```

Iptables

```
 # iptables -L -n -v
    Chain BADTCP (2 references)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
        0     0 PSCAN      tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x3F/0x29 
        0     0 PSCAN      tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x3F/0x00 
        0     0 PSCAN      tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x3F/0x01 
        0     0 PSCAN      tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x06/0x06 
        0     0 PSCAN      tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x03/0x03 
     3558  180K NEWNOTSYN  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 state NEW 

    Chain CUSTOMFORWARD (1 references)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

    Chain CUSTOMINPUT (1 references)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

    Chain CUSTOMOUTPUT (1 references)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

    Chain DHCPBLUEINPUT (1 references)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

    Chain DMZHOLES (0 references)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

    Chain GUIINPUT (1 references)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       52  2654 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 

    Chain INPUT (policy DROP 3216 packets, 183K bytes)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    22827 2000K ipac~o     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    22829 2002K BADTCP     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    22573 1991K CUSTOMINPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    22573 1991K GUIINPUT   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    14580  962K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
     7941 1026K IPSECVIRTUAL  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
     7941 1026K OPENSSLVIRTUAL  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       11   721 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW 
        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       127.0.0.0/8          0.0.0.0/0           state NEW 
        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.0/8         state NEW 
     4685  841K ACCEPT    !icmp --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW 
     3245  184K DHCPBLUEINPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
     3245  184K IPSECPHYSICAL  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
     3245  184K OPENSSLPHYSICAL  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
     3228  183K WIRELESSINPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW 
     3245  184K REDINPUT   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
     3228  183K XTACCESS   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW 
      729 47962 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 10/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `INPUT ' 

    Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 373 packets, 23367 bytes)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    5526K 2592M ipac~fi    all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    5526K 2592M ipac~fo    all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    5526K 2592M BADTCP     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    23140 1201K TCPMSS     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x06/0x02 TCPMSS clamp to PMTU 
    5522K 2592M CUSTOMFORWARD  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    2720K 2151M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    2802K  441M IPSECVIRTUAL  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    2802K  441M OPENSSLVIRTUAL  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW 
        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       127.0.0.0/8          0.0.0.0/0           state NEW 
        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.0/8         state NEW 
    2478K  359M ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW 
     325K   82M WIRELESSFORWARD  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW 
     325K   82M REDFORWARD  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
     325K   82M PORTFWACCESS  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW 
      287 19179 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 10/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `OUTPUT ' 

    Chain IPSECPHYSICAL (1 references)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

    Chain IPSECVIRTUAL (2 references)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

    Chain LOG_DROP (0 references)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
        0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 10/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 
        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

    Chain LOG_REJECT (0 references)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
        0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 10/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 
        0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 

    Chain NEWNOTSYN (1 references)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
     2927  143K LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 10/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `NEW not SYN? ' 
     3558  180K DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

    Chain OPENSSLPHYSICAL (1 references)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

    Chain OPENSSLVIRTUAL (2 references)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 23244 packets, 11M bytes)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    23240   11M ipac~i     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    23244   11M CUSTOMOUTPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

    Chain PORTFWACCESS (1 references)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            10.1.1.6            tcp dpt:5071 
        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            10.1.1.6            udp dpts:6000:10000 
        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            10.1.1.6            tcp dpt:4430 
        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            10.1.1.6            tcp dpt:4433 
        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            10.1.1.173          tcp dpt:443 
        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            10.1.1.173          udp dpt:623 
        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            10.1.1.182          tcp dpt:3389 
        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            10.1.1.182          tcp dpt:3389 
        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            10.1.1.182          tcp dpt:3389 
        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            10.1.1.182          tcp dpt:3389 
    (somethin else)


    Chain PSCAN (5 references)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
        0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 10/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `TCP Scan? ' 
        0     0 LOG        udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 10/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `UDP Scan? ' 
        0     0 LOG        icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 10/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `ICMP Scan? ' 
        0     0 LOG        all  -f  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 10/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `FRAG Scan? ' 
        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

    Chain REDFORWARD (1 references)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

    Chain REDINPUT (1 references)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

    Chain WIRELESSFORWARD (1 references)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

    Chain WIRELESSINPUT (1 references)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

    Chain XTACCESS (1 references)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   *       212.zz.xx.xy         192.168.1.130        tcp dpt:445 
        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   *       62.zz.xx.xy          192.168.1.130        tcp dpt:445 
        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   *       88.zz.xx.xy          192.168.1.130        tcp dpt:445 
        1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   *       80.zz.xx.xy          192.168.1.130        tcp dpt:222 
        1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   *       212.zz.xx.xy         192.168.1.130        tcp dpt:222 
        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   *       87.zz.xx.xy          192.168.1.130        tcp dpt:445 
        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   *       87.zz.xx.xy          192.168.1.130        tcp dpt:222 
       27  1620 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   *       80.zz.xx.xy          192.168.1.130        tcp dpt:445 

    Chain ipac~fi (1 references)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    21846   14M            all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
     5511 1324K            all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

    Chain ipac~fo (1 references)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    15836   10M            all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    11521 5209K            all  --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

    Chain ipac~i (1 references)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       20  2345            all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       29  2640            all  --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

    Chain ipac~o (1 references)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       39  5686            all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       46  3751            all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

And NAT

```
# iptables -L -v -n -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 63218 packets, 5849K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
34800 3007K CUSTOMPREROUTING  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
34800 3007K SQUID      all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
34800 3007K PORTFW     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 12692 packets, 740K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
26033 2434K CUSTOMPOSTROUTING  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
26033 2434K REDNAT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  214 11128 SNAT       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           MARK match 0x1 to:10.1.1.1 
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      eth1    10.1.1.6             0.0.0.0/0           to:192.168.1.184 
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      eth1    10.1.1.190           0.0.0.0/0           to:192.168.1.180 
19137 2022K SNAT       all  --  *      eth1    10.1.1.0/24          0.0.0.0/0           to:213.83.2.14 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1934 packets, 136K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain CUSTOMPOSTROUTING (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain CUSTOMPREROUTING (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain PORTFW (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.134        tcp dpt:25000 to:10.1.1.134:25000 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.135        tcp dpt:25000 to:10.1.1.135:25000 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.133        tcp dpt:5900 to:10.1.1.133:5900 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.134        tcp dpt:5900 to:10.1.1.134:5900 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.135        tcp dpt:5900 to:10.1.1.135:5900 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.133        tcp dpt:25000 to:10.1.1.133:25000 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.133        tcp dpt:12489 to:10.1.1.133:12489 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.134        tcp dpt:12489 to:10.1.1.134:12489 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.135        tcp dpt:12489 to:10.1.1.135:12489 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.190        tcp dpt:5900 to:10.1.1.192:5900 
    3   144 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.134        tcp dpt:443 to:10.1.1.134:443 
    3   144 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.163        tcp dpt:443 to:10.1.1.163:443 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.134        udp dpt:123 to:10.1.1.134:123 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.134        tcp dpt:123 to:10.1.1.134:123 
    3   144 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.170        tcp dpt:443 to:10.1.1.170:443 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.135        udp dpt:123 to:10.1.1.135:123 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.133        udp dpt:123 to:10.1.1.133:123 
   11   628 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.150        tcp dpt:80 to:10.1.1.150:80 
    1    52 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.150        tcp dpt:443 to:10.1.1.150:443 
    3  1309 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.150        udp dpts:1024:65535 to:10.1.1.150:1024-65535 
   71  3064 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.150        tcp dpts:1024:65535 to:10.1.1.150:1024-65535 
    2   120 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.134        tcp dpt:22 to:10.1.1.134:22 
    3   144 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.164        tcp dpt:443 to:10.1.1.164:443 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.150        udp dpts:135:139 to:10.1.1.150:135-139 
    2    96 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.150        tcp dpt:139 to:10.1.1.150:139 
    3   144 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.165        tcp dpt:443 to:10.1.1.165:443 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.135        tcp dpt:5666 to:10.1.1.135:5666 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.133        tcp dpt:5666 to:10.1.1.133:5666 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.134        tcp dpt:5666 to:10.1.1.134:5666 
    3   967 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.140        udp dpts:1024:65535 to:10.1.1.10:1024-65535 
 5250  302K DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.140        tcp dpt:80 to:10.1.1.150:80 
   74  3256 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.131        tcp dpts:1024:65535 to:10.1.1.101:1024-65535 
    2   870 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.131        udp dpts:1024:65535 to:10.1.1.101:1024-65535 
   78  3492 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.132        tcp dpts:1024:65535 to:10.1.1.102:1024-65535 
    3  1275 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.132        udp dpts:1024:65535 to:10.1.1.102:1024-65535 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.180        tcp dpt:22 to:10.1.1.190:22 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.180        udp dpt:22 to:10.1.1.190:22 
   11   628 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.141        tcp dpt:80 to:10.1.1.150:80 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.140        tcp dpt:21 to:10.1.1.10:21 
    3   144 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.161        tcp dpt:443 to:10.1.1.172:443 
    4   188 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.180        tcp dpt:80 to:10.1.1.190:80 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.180        tcp dpt:21 to:10.1.1.190:21 
    5   200 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.180        tcp dpt:3306 to:10.1.1.190:3306 
    5   212 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.140        tcp dpt:3389 to:10.1.1.10:3389 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.140        tcp dpt:5900 to:10.1.1.10:5900 
    1    60 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.181        tcp dpt:22 to:10.1.1.191:22 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.140        tcp dpt:25000 to:10.1.1.10:25000 
    2    96 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.140        tcp dpt:139 to:10.1.1.10:139 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.140        tcp dpt:514 to:10.1.1.10:514 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.140        tcp dpt:25 to:10.1.1.10:25 
    9   440 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.140        tcp dpt:445 to:10.1.1.10:445 
    5   240 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.140        tcp dpts:81:138 to:10.1.1.10:81-138 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.140        tcp dpt:8051 to:10.1.1.10:8051 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.140        tcp dpt:8161 to:10.1.1.10:8161 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.140        tcp dpt:61616 to:10.1.1.10:61616 
    3   144 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.171        tcp dpt:443 to:10.1.1.181:443 
   38  1848 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.141        tcp dpt:443 to:10.1.1.150:444 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.140        tcp dpt:5666 to:10.1.1.10:5666 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.139        tcp dpt:5666 to:10.1.1.110:5666 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.140        tcp dpt:12489 to:10.1.1.10:12489 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.139        tcp dpt:12489 to:10.1.1.110:12489 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.139        tcp dpt:5900 to:10.1.1.110:5900 
  301 15184 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.140        tcp dpt:1433 to:10.1.1.10:1433 
    2   120 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.140        tcp dpt:22 to:10.1.1.10:22 
   93  4840 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.140        tcp dpt:443 to:10.1.1.150:443 
    3   144 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.172        tcp dpt:443 to:10.1.1.180:443 
    3  1314 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.183        udp dpt:5060 to:10.1.1.5:5060 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.183        udp dpts:10000:65000 to:10.1.1.5:10000-65000 
    2   120 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.139        tcp dpt:22 to:10.1.1.110:22 
    4   160 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.139        tcp dpt:3389 to:10.1.1.110:3389 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.184        tcp dpt:5071 to:10.1.1.6:5071 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.184        udp dpts:6000:10000 to:10.1.1.6:6000-10000 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.184        tcp dpt:4430 to:10.1.1.6:4430 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.184        tcp dpt:4433 to:10.1.1.6:4433 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.180        tcp dpts:27000:29000 to:10.1.1.190:27000-29000 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.184        tcp dpt:8888 to:10.1.1.6:8888 
    3   144 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.162        tcp dpt:443 to:10.1.1.173:443 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.162        udp dpt:623 to:10.1.1.173:623 
    4   160 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.142        tcp dpt:3389 to:10.1.1.182:3389 
    4   160 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.146        tcp dpt:3389 to:10.1.1.182:3389 
    3   144 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.173        tcp dpt:443 to:10.1.1.221:443 
    3   144 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.160        tcp dpt:443 to:10.1.1.210:443 
    7   352 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.138        tcp dpt:3389 to:10.1.1.108:3389 
    5   212 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.137        tcp dpt:3389 to:10.1.1.107:3389 
    4   160 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.136        tcp dpt:3389 to:10.1.1.106:3389 
    3   144 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.168        tcp dpt:443 to:10.1.1.218:443 
    3   144 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.167        tcp dpt:443 to:10.1.1.217:443 
    3   144 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.166        tcp dpt:443 to:10.1.1.216:443 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.136        tcp dpt:5900 to:10.1.1.106:5900 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.137        tcp dpt:5900 to:10.1.1.107:5900 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.138        tcp dpt:5900 to:10.1.1.108:5900 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.150        tcp dpt:873 to:10.1.1.150:873 
    2   120 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.150        tcp dpt:22 to:10.1.1.150:22 
   46  1912 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.146        tcp dpt:1433 to:10.1.1.182:1433 
    4   160 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.181        tcp dpt:3389 to:10.1.1.191:3389 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.166        tcp dpt:23 to:10.1.1.216:23 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.168        tcp dpt:23 to:10.1.1.218:23 

Chain REDNAT (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain SQUID (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Any idea what is wrong with my Config?

Comment: What are the IPs `192.168.1.13` and `192.168.1.14` ? They're not on your connected networks, so they should go through your default gateway `192.168.1.129`... Can you post a traceroute from a client on the LAN to `192.168.1.13` ?

Comment: sorry this not the right IPs. I correct the Question.

Comment: well then, seems to me that IPCops blocks the requests going LAN -> WAN. Can you post the firewall configuration? or an `iptables -L -n -v` dump?

Comment: Thx for your answer, the output is shown in my question now

Comment: @kcockiren I don't see any relevant DROP in the chains. Have you enabled **NAT** ? Can you paste `iptables -L -v -n -t nat` too?

Comment: Of course see above for the NAT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rIn your NAT configuration, I don't see a `MASQUERADE` target.

I have no experience with IPCop configuration, and it's been a while since I configured NAT with iptables, but can you try these lines in your shell?

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

also check if

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

returns `1`. And if not, do a

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

If after these commands it works, you'll have to check your IPCop configuration on how to enable them.

Comment: thx for your help but it does not work. How can i test how the ipcop masquerade the local ip?

Comment: With your answer i search iptables for some masquerade Rules and found an Rule with the wrong ip in /etc/rc.d/rc.firewall.local and change it to the right IP /sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.1.0/24 -o $IFACE -j SNAT --to 192.168.1.130